# "pivot" table by datediff

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have the following data in a SQL table

| date | data_id | data_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-02 11:17:10.9033333 | camTray_x | 4.989 |
| 2022-05-02 11:17:10.9033333 | camTray_y | 1.308 |
| 2022-05-02 11:17:14.0966667 | camTray_x | 1.469 |
| 2022-05-02 11:17:14.1066667 | camTray_y | 2.845 |

I want to achieve the following result based on the time difference between 2 records (difference can be 0 and less than 100ms)

| date | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-02 11:17:10.9033333 | 4.989 | 1.308 |
| 2022-05-02 11:17:14.0966667 | 1.469 | 2.845 |

I am not a SQL expert and tried to mimic several simlar aproaches and I have a working solution like below

```
with xvalues as (select date, data_value as 'X' from _prod_data_line where data_id='camTray_x' ), 
yvalues as (select date, data_value as 'Y' from _prod_data_line where data_id='camTray_Y' )
    
select xvalues.date, xvalues.X, yvalues.Y from xvalues left join yvalues on 
      abs(datediff(millisecond, xvalues.date, yvalues.date))<100
```

Is this doable without the 2 selects ?

Comment: This *looks* like a straight forward pivot grouping by `date`, add clarity to your data with examples that don't meet the <100 ms criteria.

Comment: And is your goal to simplify the query? There are likely ways to write this without the two selects, but the query will be more complex because there will be window functions and other extra syntax.

Comment: What about removing millisecond data

Comment: yes the goal was to simplify the query, and I can't remove the millisecond because it is possible to have for exemple 17.990s and 18.010s . If this lead to something too complex I can live with my solution

Comment: @RF1991 presumably they'd want `4:55:24.9500000` and `4:55:25.0400000` to line up, and wouldn't want to mix them up with `4:55:25.5400000` and `4:55:25.6300000`.

Comment: Does `x` always come before `y` in the time series?

Comment: yes the order is always x -> y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will process the operation with a single scan instead of two, but it is more complex, so (as often is the case) you trade complexity for performance.

```
; -- see sqlblog.org/cte
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT date, 
    X = data_value,
    Y = LEAD(CASE WHEN data_id = 'camTray_y' THEN data_value END,1) 
             OVER (ORDER BY date),
    delta = DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, date, 
        LEAD(CASE WHEN data_id = 'camTray_y' THEN date END,1) 
             OVER (ORDER BY date))
  FROM dbo._prod_data_line
)
SELECT date, X, Y FROM cte WHERE delta <= 100;
```

Output:

| date | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-02 11:17:10.9033333 | 4.989 | 1.308 |
| 2022-05-02 11:17:14.0966667 | 1.469 | 2.845 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6d0d4af66a96ad991bf52ab71a61036a)

Also, this is a simplification, because it assumes no x/y will overlap. If you want to handle those, please provide additional edge cases like that one and those mentioned in the comments, and explain how you want them handled.